# How to create custom Upload itemRender Antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

i am using antD components in Reactjs application, I am using Upload component to upload an image , Now i want to use custom itemRender, its showing and deleting the previously uploaded images fine, but when i upload new file its not showing in the preview

```
const CustomItemRender = ({ file, fileList }) => {
    return (
      <div className="custom-item-renderer">
        <img src={fileList.url} alt={file.name} />
        <div className="buttons flex mt-1 ">
          <Button size="small" onClick={() => handlePreview(fileList)}>
            View
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" onClick={() => onRemove(fileList)}>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };


                     <Upload
                      showRemoveIcon={true}
                      showDownloadIcon={true}
                      multiple={true}
                      accept=""
                      fileList={fileList}
                      action={}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onPreview={}
                      beforeUpload={}
                      onRemove={}
                      itemRender={CustomItemRender}
                    >
                      {fileList?.length <= 9 ? uploadButton : null}
                    </Upload>
```

Answer (score -1):

check this itemRender its properly working!!

Note copy this is useState or define it on your own

```
const [preview, setPreview] = useState({
        isOpen: false,
        seeImage: '',
        setTitle: ''
   });

    
    <Upload
        itemRender={
            (file, { preview, remove }) => {
                return (
                    <div className="custom-item-renderer">
                        <img style={{ width: '64px', height: '40px' }} src={file.thumbUrl} alt={file.name} />
                        <div className="buttons flex mt-1 ">
                            <Button size="small" onClick={() => preview(
                                setPreview({
                                    isOpen: true, seeImage: file.thumbUrl, setTitle: file.name
                                })
                            )}>
                                View
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="small" onClick={() => remove(file)}>
                                Delete
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        maxCount={2}
        listType="picture"
        className="upload-list-inline"
        beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
        onChange={handleChange}
    >
        <Button icon={<Camera />}>Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
    <Modal open={preview.isOpen} title={preview.setTitle} footer={null} onCancel={() => setPreview({ isOpen: false, seeImage: '', setTitle: '' })}>
        <img style={{ width: '100%', }} src={preview.seeImage} alt="example" />
    </Modal>
```